# ASP.NET MVC, create Views with parameters, error in POST submission

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Firstly, I am teaching myself ASP.NET MVC using ASP.NET Core 2.1 with EF Core 2.1, so I'm rather noob at this.

I am trying to change a Create View, to accept an optional parameter for a ClientID. The idea is to allow selecting from all clients if no ID is supplied, but if supplied, force the form input for the client to the given value.

I am having trouble getting GET to recognize there is a parameter, unless the parameter is specifically `int? id` . If i change it to this, then when submitted to POST an exception is raised for a duplicate ID.

All Controllers and Views were scaffolded, only the GET method shown has been changed.

Controller Create GET Method:

```
// GET: ServiceRequest/Create/1
public IActionResult Create(int? clientId)
{
    ViewData["ClientData"] = new SelectList(_context.Clients, "ID", "FullName");
    if (clientId != null ) {
        if (_context.Clients.Find(clientId) == null) {
            return NotFound();
        }
        ViewData["ClientID"] = clientId;
        ViewData["ClientName"] = _context.Clients.Find(clientId).FullName;
    }
    ServiceRequest request = new ServiceRequest();
    request.Deadline = DateTime.Today;
    request.Status = Models.Status.DRAFT;
    return View(request);
}
```

Create View:

```
@model AskewServices.Models.ServiceRequest

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Open Service Request";
}

<h2>@ViewData["Title"]</h2>

<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Deadline" class="control-label"> </label>
                <input asp-for="Deadline" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Deadline" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Status" class="control-label"></label>
                <select disabled asp-for="Status" class="form-control">
                    <option value=@AskewServices.Models.Status.DRAFT>Draft</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Status" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Client</label>
                @if (ViewData.ContainsKey("ClientID")) {
                    <select disabled asp-for="ClientID" class="form-control">
                        <option value=@ViewData["ClientID"]>@ViewData["ClientName"]</option>
                    </select>    
                } else {
                    <select asp-for="ClientID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ClientData"></select>
                }                
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Open" class="btn btn-warning" />
                <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="btn btn-info" />
            </div>
       </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Routes:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "OpenServiceRequest",
                template: "{controller=ServiceRequest}/{action=Create}/{clientId?}");
        });
```

Thoughts: Parameters not being specified the right way, or a problem with Routing (it might not be seeing the ServiceRequest Create route)?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you using the default route config of ASP.Net Core like this

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

So no need to add OpenServiceRequest MapRoute